# How to automatically add claims to application's service provider

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have installed an APIM platform (4.1) with Identity Server (5.11) as key manager. When I create an new application in devportal, it generates a service provider in identity server.

How can I automatically add claims to the service provider generated at the moment a new application is created?

I tried updating the service-provider default template in WSO2_HOME/repository/conf/identity/service-provider/default.xml in both APIM and IS by adding claims configuration as follows, but it did not work:

```xml
<ClaimConfig>
    <LocalClaimDialect>true</LocalClaimDialect>
        <ClaimMapping>
         <LocalClaim>
         <ClaimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/userid</ClaimUri>
         <claimId>0</claimId>
         </LocalClaim>
         <RemoteClaim>
         <ClaimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/userid</ClaimUri>
         <claimId>0</claimId>
         </RemoteClaim>
         <RequestClaim>true</RequestClaim>
         <MandatoryClaim>false</MandatoryClaim>
        </ClaimMapping>
   <AlwaysSendMappedLocalSubjectId>false</AlwaysSendMappedLocalSubjectId>
</ClaimConfig>
```